# The springboot service of the windows system cannot connect to the kafka started with docker-compose in the cloud server

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, docker-compose

Please! Help!

I built a stand-alone kafka service through docker-compose on the cloud server (ip: 49.234.12.199).

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    depends_on: [ zookeeper ]
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 49.234.12.199
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://49.234.12.199:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I can normally call port 9092 of 49.234.12.199 through the telnet command, and I can also create topics normally through commands inside the container.

But on my local windows system computer, the service started by springboot can't call the kafka service in docker normally, which makes me crazy.

The relevant configuration of springboot is as follows：

1. maven

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <artifactId>boot-kafka</artifactId>
    <name>boot-kafka</name>
    <description>Kafka demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

2. application.yml

```
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: 49.234.12.199:9092
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
    producer:
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      retries: 3

kafka:
  topic:
    my-topic: my-topic
    my-topic2: my-topic2
```

3. KafkaConfig.class

```
package org.liu.demo.config;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.RecordMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.StringJsonMessageConverter;

@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.topic.my-topic}")
    private String myTopic;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.my-topic2}")
    private String myTopic2;

    
    @Bean
    public RecordMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
        return new StringJsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic myTopic() {
        return new NewTopic(myTopic, 2, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic myTopic2() {
        return new NewTopic(myTopic2, 1, (short) 1);
    }
}
```

Finally start the error message

```
E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:52858,suspend=y,server=n -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:C:\Users\yue.liu2\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.2\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\charsets.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\deploy.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\javaws.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jce.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jfr.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\jsse.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\plugin.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\resources.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\rt.jar;E:\个人项目\boot-related-frame-study\boot-kafka\target\classes;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.1.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.26\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.9\jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.9\jackson-core-2.9.9.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.9\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.9.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.9\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.9.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.9\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.9.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.21\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.21\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.21.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.21\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.17.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\classmate-1.4.0.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\kafka\spring-kafka\2.2.7.RELEASE\spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\retry\spring-retry\1.2.4.RELEASE\spring-retry-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\apache\kafka\kafka-clients\2.0.1\kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\lz4\lz4-java\1.4.1\lz4-java-1.4.1.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\xerial\snappy\snappy-java\1.1.7.1\snappy-java-1.1.7.1.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;E:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.8.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar;D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" org.liu.demo.BootKafkaApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52858', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2020-09-30 17:45:09.656  INFO 3268 --- [           main] org.liu.demo.BootKafkaApplication        : Starting BootKafkaApplication on SH-CODE-PC0638 with PID 3268 (started by yue.liu2 in E:\个人项目\boot-related-frame-study)
2020-09-30 17:45:09.658  INFO 3268 --- [           main] org.liu.demo.BootKafkaApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-30 17:45:10.179  INFO 3268 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$880d02f5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-09-30 17:45:10.339  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2020-09-30 17:45:10.354  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-09-30 17:45:10.354  INFO 3268 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2020-09-30 17:45:10.359  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.24] using APR version [1.7.0].
2020-09-30 17:45:10.359  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2020-09-30 17:45:10.359  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
2020-09-30 17:45:10.361  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020]
2020-09-30 17:45:10.419  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-09-30 17:45:10.419  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 732 ms
2020-09-30 17:45:10.576  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-09-30 17:45:10.749  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
    bootstrap.servers = [49.234.12.199:9092]
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 120000
    retries = 5
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS

2020-09-30 17:45:10.780  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 2.0.1
2020-09-30 17:45:10.780  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5
2020-09-30 17:45:49.400 ERROR 3268 --- [           main] o.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin  : Could not configure topics

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Timed out waiting to get existing topics; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.lambda$checkPartitions$2(KafkaAdmin.java:238) [spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.checkPartitions(KafkaAdmin.java:213) [spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.addTopicsIfNeeded(KafkaAdmin.java:199) [spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.initialize(KafkaAdmin.java:169) [spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaAdmin.java:139) [spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862) [spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) [spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) [spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.liu.demo.BootKafkaApplication.main(BootKafkaApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:108) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:274) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.lambda$checkPartitions$2(KafkaAdmin.java:216) [spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted

2020-09-30 17:45:59.401  INFO 3268 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Forcing a hard I/O thread shutdown. Requests in progress will be aborted.
2020-09-30 17:45:59.421  INFO 3268 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path ''
2020-09-30 17:45:59.423  INFO 3268 --- [           main] org.liu.demo.BootKafkaApplication        : Started BootKafkaApplication in 50.077 seconds (JVM running for 50.591)
```

Comment: I suggest testing using `kafka-console` commands before trying Spring. Based on the error, `kafka-topics --create` should even fail. Also, most cloud providers now offer their own hosted-Kafka solutions, so you shouldnt need Docker at all

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` config. I am guessing you would need the public host name for the Docker cloud server.

The following article might help with configuring this correctly:
https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/